# installing plpython3u for postgresql 9.6 under windows 7

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I've used EnterpriseDB stackbuilder to install postgres9.6 and the language-pack. Postgres9.6 is installed under C:\Program Files folder while the edb lanaguge pack is installed under C:\edb.

However, it seems that I cannot create the plpython3u extension because it cannot find some necessary modules. How do I get postgres to find my python language pack installation?

When I type CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u is says:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not be found.
```

NOTE: I already use Python 3.6 for development, so I'd rather not change the entire installation, I just want to point postgres to the proper runtime so plpython3.dll can load up.

Do I have to change some environment variables?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?